# How to make sure string is being given a proper format

Tags: string, powershell, formatting

I'm coding a progress bar for my script, and I've run into an issue where a string is being fed data in an incorrect format.

```
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    #Set UserPrincipalName for current user
    $upn = $User

    #Display progress bar
    $percentage = [math]::Round($loopcount / $maxcount *100)
    $message = "Applying changes for $upn  ($loopcount of $maxcount)" -f $percentage
    Write-Progress -Activity $message -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -PercentComplete ($percentage) -Status "Progress $percentage% :"
```

This is the main part of the code that makes up the progress bar (there's more, but that's irrelevant). It works great when it is being fed user identities (via `$User`) like "delat" and "damo", but when it gets to a user called "DiscoverySearch {D919BA05-46A6-415f-80AD-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}" it understandably throws a "Error formatting a string" error.

How do I go about solving this issue?

**Edit:** Below is the source of `$User`, in case that's needed.

```
$MailboxRegionList = Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration
$Users += $MailboxRegionList | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Identity
```

Comment: You can use the `RecipientTypeDetails` parameter on `Get-Mailbox` to filter the results by the specified mailbox subtype like `UserMailbox`. See [Get-Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps)

Answer (score 1):

This happens, as `-f $percentage` is not doing what you'd expect. It is not going to format the message as percentage a value.

```
$message = "Applying changes for $upn  ($loopcount of $maxcount)" -f $percentage
```

The [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6), `-f` will fill in a value in string. The placeholder is to be marked with curly brackets `{}`, which your string doesn't usually have. When the `$user` is `DiscoverySearch {D919BA05-46A6-415f-80AD-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}`, it contains curly brackets. Now, the curly brackets should follow .Net [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) syntax, and a GUID in account name does not do that.

As for a fix, try

```
$message = "Applying changes for $upn  ($loopcount of $maxcount) $percentage"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue:
`$message = "Applying changes for $upn  ($loopcount of $maxcount) {0}%" -f $percentage`
If you understood your answer correctly, there shouldn't even be a possibility that a account name contains curly brackets? Would you say that it's unnecessary to account for those names, and that the progress bar is fine as is?

Comment: @Atheos DiscoverySearch is part of Exchange's [internal workings](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/discovery-mailbox). I don't have a test environment at hand, but in most cases one shouldn't mess with such accounts without good reason and Microsoft's documentation to support.

Comment: I looked into "DiscoverySearch", and of course you are correct - my script shouldn't handle it. I semi-fixed my issue by making sure "DiscoverySearch" wasn't added to "$Users". However, my script would still throw the format error if I ever encounter a tenant with a user that's got curly brackets in its name.
Should I change the script to account for that?